# Why can't I define a function using the Minimization function in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I define a function in this way:

`function[x_,y_]=Minimize[E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + x*y + x*z + x*w + y*z + y*w + z*w), {z,w}]`

The output in Mathematica will give me the minimal value of the expression and the values for z and w that minimize the expression.  If I want to extract just the minimum value for this output, I can call
`function[1,1][[1]]`
and this will return the minimal value.  Now, suppose I want to define a new function that returns this minimal value, i.e., define:

`function2[x_,y_] = function[x,y][[1]]`

If I call `function2[1,1]`, I don't get the minimal value that was output when calling `function[1,1][[1]]`, but rather an expression involving the variables z and w.  Is there any way to fix this and accomplish my goal of defining a new function that extracts the minimal value from Minimize?

Comment: (1) Consider using [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999)  on the parameters `x` and `y`. (2) Define `function2` with [`:=` instead of `=`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/4999).

Comment: I was searching for the link.  I just added it to my comment.  The formal names for `:=` and `=` are `SetDelayed` and `Set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[
   E^(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + x*y + x*z + x*w + y*z + y*w + z*w), {z, 
    w}][[1]];
f[1,1]
```

Comment: The comment have solve the question :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your definitions use `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in their definitions. `=` evaluates its right hand side on the spot. You get away with that for `function` because `Minimize` can't do the job for unknown `x` and `y`, so evaluation does nothing. But in `function2`, `Part` extracts the first part of the `Minimize` expression, and that becomes the definition. It works if you do:

```
function2[x_, y_] := function[x, y][[1]]
```

because `:=` delays evaluation until you "call" `function2`. I'd recommend using `:=` in the definition of `function` also, because the fact that your definition works is a bit of an accident.

Comment: @LunarCrater just as an aside/fyi, for SE sites like this, it is often better to let your questions collect answers over some 24 hours or so before accepting an answer so as to get the best answer possible (& get more answers, too!)

Comment: @LunarCrater No problem, I do this for fun, not for points.

Comment: @LunarCrater See cvgmt's answer and learn to use `?NumericQ`.